# TFS 11 installation failure at creating web site  : TF255077

Tags: installation

Is there someone know why i could not install the Team Foundation Server 2011 while i just uninstalled TFS 2010, and sources is important to my company.. any ideas on how to overcome this issues ?? The result returned is

> The access control list (ACL) could not be set on the following path: C:\Windows\temp.

Portion of error log

```
[Info   @14:51:21.458] +-+-+-+-+-| Running SetApplicationACLs: Setting file system permissions ... |+-+-+-+-+-
[Info   @14:51:21.458] 
[Info   @14:51:21.458] +-+-+-+-+-| Setting file system permissions ... |+-+-+-+-+-
[Info   @14:51:21.458] Starting Node: CSETATACLS
[Info   @14:51:21.458] NodePath : Container/Progress/CSETATACLS
[Info   @14:51:21.462] Adding modify access for identity TFS_APPTIER_SERVICE_WPG to path C:\Windows\temp
[Error  @14:51:21.464] 
Exception Message: TF255077: The access control list (ACL) could not be set on the following path: C:\Windows\temp. (type ConfigurationException)

Exception Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.Filesystem.SetAcls(String[] identities, String[] pathsForAccess, ITFLogger logger)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.ConfigureSetApplicationAcls.Run(ActivityContext context)

Inner Exception Details:

Exception Message: Some or all identity references could not be translated. (type IdentityNotMappedException)

Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Security.Principal.NTAccount.Translate(IdentityReferenceCollection sourceAccounts, Type targetType, Boolean forceSuccess)
   at System.Security.Principal.NTAccount.Translate(Type targetType)
   at System.Security.AccessControl.CommonObjectSecurity.ModifyAccess(AccessControlModification modification, AccessRule rule, Boolean& modified)
   at System.Security.AccessControl.CommonObjectSecurity.AddAccessRule(AccessRule rule)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.RealAdminExternals.Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.IAdminExternals.AddAccessToDirectory(String groupName, FileSystemRights rights, String path)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.Filesystem.SetAcls(String[] identities, String[] pathsForAccess, ITFLogger logger)

[Info   @14:51:21.464] Node returned: Error
[Error  @14:51:21.464] TF255077: The access control list (ACL) could not be set on the following path: C:\Windows\temp.
[Info   @14:51:21.464] Completed SetApplicationACLs: Error
[Info   @14:51:21.464] -----------------------------------------------------
[Info   @14:51:21.465] 
[Info   @14:51:21.465] +-+-+-+-+-| ResultsSqmData |+-+-+-+-+-
[Info   @14:51:21.465] Feature: ApplicationTier (1)
[Info   @14:51:21.466] Feature: ApplicationTier; previousFailure: True
[Info   @14:51:21.466] Error count: 1
[Info   @14:51:21.466] Warning count: 0
[Info   @14:51:21.466] Overall Result: Failure (3)
[Info   @14:51:21.488] WebSiteData: 9
[Info   @14:51:21.489] SqlData: 0
[Info   @14:51:21.489] RSData: 0
[Info   @14:51:21.489] WSSData: 0
[Info   @14:51:21.489] Wizard: Basics (9)
[Info   @14:51:21.489] TfsConfigData: 16390
[Info   @14:51:21.490] serviceLevel: Dev11.CTP2
[Info   @14:51:21.490] Fatal Error Location: 139
[Info   @14:51:21.490] Activity = ApplicationTierBasic (1)
[Info   @14:51:21.536] ResultSqmData.UpdateIssues
[Info   @14:51:21.536] no issues
```

**UPDATE** - After reinstall, it's still not working. Any solution ?

Comment: Seems like a SuperUser question to me (even though it's a dev tool).  Also: don't uninstall your live TFS instance (because that's what it sounds like you've done) until you know you have a functioning alternative.  Sources *are* important, so you should be careful with them... ;-)

Comment: i did @.@ after i uninstalled only noticed that... btw, i got no way back for the moment while my TFS 2010 key is missing and what i left is this crashed application... trying to re-install and wondering how could it related to ACL...

Comment: Did you get this working?  Go look at security tab (permissions) on the temp folder.  See if there's a permission wit an identity that can't be resolved (it shows up as a SID instead of a friendly name).  Try removing that ACL then try again.

Comment: @bryanmac yea, previously the version from microsoft got some problems... and solved

Comment: @Slim - I'm on that team so I'm interested in how you solved it :) I want to make sure we shouldn't react in the product somehow ...

Comment: @bryanmac , simply download again from microsoft.. i guess the latest should be no such problem because last time still remember microsoft guy told me this error caused by something missing... maybe some error occurred while download ? and i used to didn't check MD5 =P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not sound like an ISO or corruption issue.  If you'll send the full logs to tfcare at microsoft dt com we'll look at it and post back here with the result(s).

You should have seen a UI / link with this contact info on the failure (if you didn't I'd like to know that too) - I'd encourage anyone with beta setup or configuration issues to use this.  It goes straight to the product team, and we review and fix these issues daily.

Answer (score 2):

This could happen because corrupted ISO or file, try to download the source again, it happen with me, see the following link that describe this problem.

http://mohamedradwan.wordpress.com/2012/03/06/upgrade-tfs-11-beta-failure-and-its-solution/

You can find also very helpful links there on how to upgrade step by step

Comment: The application is now installed but could not configure the basic and failed at the same point; creating website (after creating database)

Comment: What basic? you will upgrade, did you see my post about upgrading??  http://mohamedradwan.wordpress.com/2012/03/07/upgrade-tfs-2010-to-tfs-11-beta-step-by-step-and-its-prerequisites/

Comment: No.. i meaning the first configuration, no share point but just tfs and failed to install

Comment: OK, The second answer by EdH (Ed Holloway) He is a Microsoft guy, and he is very helpful person, so as he said, you can send any error to Microsoft tfcare, it' better to attach the log file

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Avast antivirus, please disable Avast self-defense module and try to configure TFS again.